# Dates, lubridate incrementing by 1 month

Tags: r, lubridate

I am having trouble using lubridate to increment by 1 month from 2013-09-30 (last day of September) to 2013-10-31 (last day of October).

The example provided in the documentation works well:

```
# get a vector of months (last day of the month)
vct_dates <- ymd("2013-01-31") %m+% months(0:11)
```

The following gives 2013-10-31 as expected:

```
vct_dates[10]
```

And, the following gives 2013-09-30:

```
vct_dates[9]
```

But, when I try and increment 2013-09-30 by one month, I get the wrong answer:

```
# should be 2013-10-31 but is 2013-10-30
vct_dates[9] %m+% months(1)
```

Any ideas...?

Comment: "But, when I try and increment 2013-09-30 by one month, I get the wrong answer". Actually, it gave you the right answer.

Comment: Okay thanks PL..."I received an answer different to what I was expecting"

Answer (score 3):

Neither R nor lubridate have a notion of 'last day in month'. But you can trick it:  Take the *first day of the next month*, increment that by a month -- and subtract a day:

```
R> seq(as.Date("2016-10-01"), by="1 month", len=2)-1
[1] "2016-09-30" "2016-10-31"
R>
```

This works in base R without any add-on packages.

Comment: This is awesome!

Answer (score 1):

What about :

```
vct_dates <- (ymd("2013-09-30") + days(1))  %m+% months(0:11) + days(-1)
```